# Is it possible to dynamically adjust the priority of outgoing emails?

Tags: email, email-server

This is more of a theoretical question, but is it possible to dynamically, and on an ongoing basis, adjust the priority of emails in the mail queue?

For example, for all mail, set it's priority (`p`) to `1` (meaning send immediately). If `N` emails in the last `M` share similar or identical content, adjust the priority of this email such that it's priority is in the range `[0..1]` so that `p` is equal to `1 - N/M` and other email can get sent before the similar/identical stuff.

Or, if you have another idea or standard what is it?

Some background: Someone put a `mail()` call in an infinite loop... And now we have to wait for the mail queue to catch up before anyone can send or receive mail again.

Answer (score 0):

With `exim` you can use the `-Mf <id> <id>...` option to freeze messages. Which MTA are you using?